# How can I change the values of this matrix in a way that can have an array with numbers and an array with words?

Tags: java

I am creating a matrix that has a row of names and another of ages, I want to change the values of the first row of "names" to convert them from numbers to letters. (But I have to guarantee that 1 will always be John for example)

```
private static int matrixNameAge[][] = new {1,2,3},{30,10,25};

}

    static String obtainNumbersPerIndex(int pIndex){

        String name = "";

        switch(pIndex){
           case 1:    
                name = "John";
                break;
            case 2:    
                name = "Cristine";
                break;
            case 3:    
                name = "Peter";
                break;
 default:
                name = "Nombre not found"; 
                break;
        }

        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Create a class with `name` and `age` and declare an array of those.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional Arrays in Java are of the same type. You can't have a 2D array with a row of strings and another of integers.
You can either

1. have two separate arrays one `String[]` the names and one `int[]` with the ages having corresponding indexes
2. use a `Pair<String, int>[]` to bundle both values together.
3. If you can guarantee uniqueness in your strings, a map wouldn't be a bad idea either